# Converting Div To Dropdown (with data-value)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, radio-button, dropdown

I'm using a plugin (FacetWP) along with Advanced Custom Fields to add a search filter to my website. There is a Range List function which styles the data as a radio list with ranges like 1-4, 4-5 etc. I need to style it like a dropdown select though. I have achieved this by using the below coding:

```js
var sel = $('<select class="facetwp-dropdown" id="new_facet"/>');
$('#new_facet div').each(function(){
    sel.append('<option value='+this.dataset.value+'>'+this.innerHTML+'</option>')
})
        
$('#new_facet').replaceWith(sel)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new_facet" class="facetwp-facet facetwp-facet-new_facet facetwp-type-range_list" data-name="new_facet" data-type="range_list">
        <div class="facetwp-radio" data-value="1-10">1+</div>
        <div class="facetwp-radio" data-value="2-10">2+</div>
        <div class="facetwp-radio" data-value="3-10">3+</div>
        <div class="facetwp-radio" data-value="4-10">4+</div>
        </div>
```

But, I can't work out how to use the data-value in a dropdown. As you can see, I've added it to my Javascript but it's not actually gathering any data. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're collecting the data attribute in the wrong way.

Try this

jQuery >= 1.4.3

```
$('#new_facet div').each(function(i,e){
  sel.append('<option value='+$(e).data('value')+'>'+$(e).html()+'</option>')
});
```

or

```
$('#new_facet div').each(function(i,e){
  sel.append('<option value='+$(e).attr("data-value")+'>'+$(e).html()+'</option>')
});
```

Comment: Thanks - when I inspect the element it shows <option value="1-10"> etc but it's still not returning any data.

Comment: Your question was how to set the data-value attribute in your new `<select>` html element. Processing the selected option to the database is a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

From jquery website

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically
>   pulled in to jQuery's data object.

For example if your html is

```
<div id="myDiv" data-role="page"></div>
```

You can get the role as follow

```
$( "#myDiv" ).data( "role" )
```

So for your example here is the full working code:

```js
var sel = $('<select class="facetwp-dropdown" id="new_facet"/>');
$('#new_facet div').each(function(){
  console.log("data-value: "+$(this).data('value'));
  sel.append('<option value='+$(this).data('value')+'>'+$(this).html()+'</option>');
});
        
$('#new_facet').replaceWith(sel)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="new_facet" class="facetwp-facet facetwp-facet-new_facet facetwp-type-range_list" data-name="new_facet" data-type="range_list">
    <div class="facetwp-radio" data-value="1-10">1+</div>
    <div class="facetwp-radio" data-value="2-10">2+</div>
    <div class="facetwp-radio" data-value="3-10">3+</div>
    <div class="facetwp-radio" data-value="4-10">4+</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - when I inspect the element it shows <option value="1-10"> etc but it's still not returning any data.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you need ? What do you mean by "still not returning any data" ? An html is not supposed to return any data.

Comment: I'm using it to filter the search of listings for a real estate website - see http://www.elevateresidential.com.au/tenants/listings/ it needs to add the extension to the domain so that is shows results inline with the search ie. http://www.elevateresidential.com.au/tenants/listings/?_min_bedrooms=1-10

Comment: @PortfolioCreative, what do you mean by "not returning any data"? Is this the code you're missing: `$('#new_facet').on('change', function(){console.log($(this).val());});`?